# Exercise 1.3 SICP why doesn't it work with 'when'?

Tags: scheme, racket, sicp

```
#!/usr/bin/env racket
#lang racket/base

;Define a procedure that takes three numbers as arguments and returns the sum of the
;squares of the two larger numbers.

(define (procsq a b c)
  (when (and (< a b)(> c a))(+ (* b b)(* c c))) 
  (when (and (< a c)(> b a))(+ (* b b)(* c c)))
  (when (and (< b a)(> c b))(+ (* a a)(* c c)))
  (when (and (< b c)(> a b))(+ (* a a)(* c c)))
  (when (and (< c a)(> b a))(+ (* a a)(* b b)))
  (when (and (< c b)(> a c))(+ (* a a)(* b b)))) 

(displayln (procsq 1 2 3)); Why does it print #<void> ?
(displayln (procsq 3 2 1))
(displayln (procsq 3 1 2)); Why does it print #<void> ?
```

I coded my answer using when, why doesn't it work? The comments show with what arguments
it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A procedure returns the value of the last expression in the body. Each `when` is calculating a value, but they're not being returned because it's not the last expression. It then goes to the next `when`. The result is the value of the last `when`, which will be `#<void>` if the condition isn't true.

Use `cond` when you have a series of mutually-exclusive conditions, not separate `when` expressions. It will return the value corresponding to the first condition that's true.

```
(define (procsq a b c)
  (cond ((and (< a b)(> c a)) (+ (* b b)(* c c)))
        ((and (< a c)(> b a)) (+ (* b b)(* c c)))
        ((and (< b a)(> c b)) (+ (* a a)(* c c)))
        ((and (< b c)(> a b)) (+ (* a a)(* c c)))
        ((and (< c a)(> b a)) (+ (* a a)(* b b)))
        ((and (< c b)(> a c)) (+ (* a a)(* b b)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally, a procedure returns the value of the last expression in the body, as is explained in the other answer.

In many other languages though we have the ability to return immediately from within the depths of a running procedure. Scheme too has such capability, though not through a keyword but what's known a continuation mechanism:

```
(define (procsq a b c)
  (call-with-current-continuation
    (lambda (return)
      (when (and (< a b)(> c a)) (return (+ (* b b)(* c c)))) 
      (when (and (< a c)(> b a)) (return (+ (* b b)(* c c))))
      (when (and (< b a)(> c b)) (return (+ (* a a)(* c c))))
      (when (and (< b c)(> a b)) (return (+ (* a a)(* c c))))
      (when (and (< c a)(> b a)) (return (+ (* a a)(* b b))))
      (when (and (< c b)(> a c)) (return (+ (* a a)(* b b)))))))

;; > (procsq 1 2 3)
;; 13
```

Comment: When can I read more on `return`? Occassionally, not related to this code, I have to do something like this: `(return (values (list-ref my-list 0) (list-ref my-list 1)))` but it does not work because of the arity mismatch. I've found only this `https://docs.racket-lang.org/algebraic/class_base.html#%28def._%28%28lib._algebraic%2Fcontrol%2Fmonad..rkt%29._return%29%29` but it does no seem to be the same `return` as in your code.

Comment: the `return` in my code is an wholly arbitrary name. I could have named it `exit` or `qq` just the same. it's just a name which captures the current continuation, courtesy of the [`call-with-current-continuation`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/cont.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._call-with-current-continuation%29%29).

Comment: see also [`call-with-escape-continuation`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/cont.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._call-with-escape-continuation%29%29). the first is also present in Scheme, the latter only in Racket.